# How to Load multiple angular2 components from different folders in one index.html file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, relative-path

I have developed few angular 2 components. 
the directory structure for my application is following.
[image: This is the directory structure of my application]

and I am loading each component from index.html as

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: { 'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs' },
    packages: {
        app: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'}           
    }
  });
  System.import('component_1/app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

what I have done is , there must be only one index.html and according to the path provided inside **System.config** I will be able to load different components.
I am able to load the components if I am placing index.html inside each components folder,but i want to use only one index.html for all components by calling **main.ts** of each component from that index.html.

Following are my code details.

1. index.html

```html
<html>
  <head>    
    <title>Angular 2 TypeScript App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>  
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        map: { 'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs' },
        packages: {
            app: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'}           
        }
      });
      System.import('component_1/app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

2.main.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

3.app.component.ts

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgSwitch, NgSwitchWhen, NgSwitchDefault,NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { DataService } from '../app/services/data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [DataService],
    template: '<h1>{{record.data}}</h1>',
    directives: [NgSwitch, NgSwitchWhen, NgSwitchDefault]
})
export class AppComponent {
    public record;    
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
    ngOnInit() {        
        this.dataService.getData()
        .subscribe((customers:any[]) => {
            this.record = customers;
        });   
  }  
}
```

4.data.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }    
    getData() {
        return this.http.get('../../uicomponent.json')
                        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

I have tried all methods, but my index.html is not redirecting to my main.ts to load my component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define each `component_*` folder into your SystemJS configuration:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
    },
    packages: {
        'component_1': { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'component_2': { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        (...)
        'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'}           
    }
  });
  System.import('component_1/app/main')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

This way you will be able to use the `component_*` (for example `component_1` in your imports).

If you want to keep your configuration and be able to use all components, you should move your `component_*` folders under the `app` folder...

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to define each `component_*` folder in your SystemJS configuration...

Comment: using your code..its working..but now JSON file is not getting retireved..its showing error as resource not found.404..

Comment: How do you load this JSON file?

Comment: I have updated my question description for data.service.ts.it is inside **services** folder

Comment: I would use an absolute path: `/component_1/app/uicomponent.json`

Comment: i tried that too.still its not finding the json file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102900/discussion-between-bhushan-gadekar-and-thierry-templier).

Comment: Strange for the absolute path. I think that you should have a look at the JavaScript console or the Network tab of developer tools of your browser to see the actual HTTP request that is executed. This way, you will be able to tweak the path to find out the correct one... According to your screenshot (if `uicomponent.json` is under the `/component_1/app/uicomponent.json`), the absolute path I gave you should work.

Comment: it worked now.. I think absolute path is necessary..thanks for the help bro :)