# Importing Angualr2 Component from different directory

Tags: angular, typescript

Given the below folder structure, I am trying to import `app.overlay.component.ts` into my `tracker.component.ts` using `@ViewChild`. WebStorm is OK with the file path but when I run the application in the browser, I get an error saying that it can't find the `showOverlay` method. I'm reading that I need to make some adjustments to my System.config.js but the changes I'm making aren't resolving the path. If making the system.config.js fix the right way? My understanding was the using `moduleId: module.id` is supposed to help with relative paths but I think my understanding is incorrect. I have based by system.config.js changes off this thread ([How to Load multiple angular2 components from different folders in one index.html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269390/how-to-load-multiple-angular2-components-from-diffrent-folders-in-one-index-html))

I tried using the same code on a component at the same level as the shared folder and everything worked as expected so my assumption is my path is incorrect or there is a different configuration required

**Error** `TypeError: Cannot read property 'showOverlay' of undefined`

**NOTE** Forget about the jquery in the component. That will go away as I know it's incorrect. Just for testing purposes as of now.

`root
  -public
    -app
      -ts
        -pages
          -tracker
            -tracker.component.ts
        -shared
          -app.overlay.component.ts`

**app.overlay.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({

    selector: 'overlay-component',
    templateUrl: '/public/app/templates/shared/overlay.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../app/scss/shared/overlay.css']

})

export class OverlayComponent  {


    showOverlay() {
        $('.overlay-component-container').show();
    }

    hideOverlay() {
        $('.overlay-component-container').hide();
    }

}
```

**tracker.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { OverlayComponent } from "../../shared/app.overlay.component"; //WebStorm says this path is OK but is this.overlayComponent is undefined at runtime


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'beertracker-component',
    templateUrl: '/public/app/templates/pages/tracker/tracker.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../../scss/pages/tracker/tracker.css']
})

export class BeerTrackerComponent implements OnInit{


    @ViewChild(OverlayComponent) private overlayComponent: OverlayComponent;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.overlayComponent);
        this.overlayComponent.showOverlay();
    }
}
```

**System.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        defaultJSExtensions: true, //manual add
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: '../public/app/ts/main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'shared': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Comment: If you are not using a bundler, check your browser's net connections to see that it attempted to load the component file.

Comment: Please post contents of /public/app/templates/shared/overlay.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use ngAfterViewInit() and not ngOnInit() because it runs after viewchild components are initialized.

Comment: ngAfterViewInit is not required for ViewChild. I have also verified the code works when the component referencing OverlayComponent as the sibling level works.

Comment: As a sibling did you load it like this:
import { OverlayComponent } from "./app.overlay.component"

Comment: "./shared/app.overaly.component" but yes.

Comment: This is what I had : `import {OverlayComponent} from "./shared/app.overlay.component";`

Comment: I've done relative paths, so I don't know why yours won't work if your file tree diagram is correct (I would check the browser net connections to see if file was not found).

However the solution you linked to is asking you to map your path in the SystemJS config and not use relative paths. So you can try using your "app" path since it is already mapped, like so:

import { OverlayComponent } from "app/ts/shared/app.overlay.component"

Note how it starts with "app/" -- so the SystemJS config should direct it to the path mapped

Comment: Yea, it's very confusing. Whenever I change the path in WebStorm to anything other than what I have, it throws a compiler error for 'module not found'

Comment: Note also that your OverlayComponent has a relative path for a stylesheet with styleUrls. You can remove that to make sure that is not causing a problem if file is not found.

Comment: And also, chrome dev tools shows the response was succesfull and I see the files content in the response. So frustrating.

Comment: I'm more than happy to do a screen share if you have time.

Comment: sure, does stackoverflow have a messenger/mailbox to trade info

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. Do you have skype? I will send you my handler and delete after hearing from you.